# Bug in authorization filter(JEE6)

Tags: java, security, jakarta-ee, java-ee-6, servlet-filters

I am writing an authorization filter for my JEE6 application, to be able to restrict access to certain users to some pages. For some reason the browser doesn't display any page at all(I just see white). There has to be a bug somewhere but i don't know where, i am new to JEE6 security and i am trying to implement my authentication mechanism in the easiest possible way.

Here is my source code

The filter:

```
public class RestrictPageFilter implements Filter {

    private FilterConfig fc;
    private InputStream in;
    private Access access;

    public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException {
        // The easiest way to initialize the filter
        fc = filterConfig;

        // Prepare the parsing
        try {
            in = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader()
                    .getResourceAsStream("allowedpages.xml");
            Access access = (Access) JAXBContext.newInstance(Access.class)
                    .createUnmarshaller().unmarshal(in);
        } catch (JAXBException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response,
            FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {

        HttpServletRequest req = (HttpServletRequest) request;
        HttpServletResponse resp = (HttpServletResponse) response;
        HttpSession session = req.getSession(true);
        String pageRequested = req.getRequestURL().toString();

        // Get the value of the current logged user
        Role currentUser = (Role) session.getAttribute("userRole");
        if (currentUser != null) {
            if (currentUser.getType().equals("BUYER")) {
                List<String> buyerPages = access.getBuyer().getPages();
                for (String s : buyerPages) {
                    if (pageRequested.contains(s)) {
                        chain.doFilter(request, response);
                    } else {
                        resp.sendRedirect("main.xml");
                    }
                }
            } else if (currentUser.getType().equals("SELLER")) {
                List<String> buyerPages = access.getSeller().getPages();
                for (String s : buyerPages) {
                    if (pageRequested.contains(s)) {
                        chain.doFilter(request, response);
                    } else {
                        resp.sendRedirect("main.xml");
                    }
                }
            } else if (currentUser.getType().equals("ADMINISTRATOR")) {
                List<String> buyerPages = access.getAdministrator().getPages();
                for (String s : buyerPages) {
                    if (pageRequested.contains(s)) {
                        chain.doFilter(request, response);
                    } else {
                        resp.sendRedirect("main.xml");
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public void destroy() {
        // Not needed
    }
}
```

To support this filter i use a .xml file(located in WEB-INF/classes) that contains the allowed pages and also a bean to store the details of the .xml as an object:

```
<access>
    <buyer>
        <page>buyoffer.xhtml</page>
        <page>faq.xhtml</page>
        <page>index.jsp</page>
        <page>login.xhtml</page>
        <page>main.xhtml</page>
        <page>registrationSucceded.xhtml</page>     
    </buyer>
    <seller>
        <page>sellerpanel.xhtml</page>
        <page>faq.xhtml</page>
        <page>index.jsp</page>
        <page>login.xhtml</page>
        <page>main.xhtml</page>
        <page>registrationSucceded.xhtml</page>     
    </seller>
    <administrator>
        <page>sellerpanel.xhtml</page>
        <page>faq.xhtml</page>
        <page>index.jsp</page>
        <page>login.xhtml</page>
        <page>main.xhtml</page>
        <page>registrationSucceded.xhtml</page>     
    </administrator>
</access>
```

--

```
package simplebeans;

import java.util.List;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

@XmlRootElement
public class Access {

    @XmlElement
    private User buyer;

    @XmlElement
    private User seller;

    @XmlElement
    private User administrator;

    public User getBuyer() {
        return buyer;
    }

    public User getSeller() {
        return seller;
    }

    public User getAdministrator() {
        return administrator;
    }

    @XmlRootElement
    public static class User {

        @XmlElement(name="page")
        private List<String> pages;

        public List<String> getPages() {
            return pages;
        }

    }

}
```

This is how i add the filter to the web.xml file:

```
<!--Page restriction filter -->
    <filter>
        <filter-name>restrict</filter-name>
        <filter-class>filters.RestrictPageFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>restrict</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
```

What do you think is the reason i only see white in my browser? 
I try to navigate using the URL to some of the pages, but i see only white.

**Update**
I made a few changes to be able to allow users that at not logged in to see some of the pages but i get a NPE:

Changes at the doFilter method:

```
public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response,
            FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {

        HttpServletRequest req = (HttpServletRequest) request;
        HttpServletResponse resp = (HttpServletResponse) response;
        HttpSession session = req.getSession(true);
        String pageRequested = req.getRequestURL().toString();

        // Get the value of the current logged user
        Role currentUser = (Role) session.getAttribute("userRole");
        boolean authorized = false;

        if (!pageRequested.contains("main.xhtml") && currentUser != null) {

            switch (currentUser.getType()) {
            case BUYER:
                for (String s : access.getBuyer().getPages()) {
                    if (pageRequested.contains(s)) {
                        authorized = true;
                    }
                }
                break;
            case SELLER:
                for (String s : access.getSeller().getPages()) {
                    if (pageRequested.contains(s)) {
                        authorized = true;
                    }
                }
                break;
            case ADMINISTRATOR:
                for (String s : access.getAdministrator().getPages()) {
                    if (pageRequested.contains(s)) {
                        authorized = true;
                    }
                }
                break;
            }
        }
        else {
            for (String s : access.getVisitor().getPages()) {
                if (pageRequested.contains(s)) {
                    authorized = true;
                }
            }
        }


        if (authorized || pageRequested.contains("main.xhtml")) {
            chain.doFilter(request, response);
        } else {
            resp.sendRedirect("main.xhtml");
        }
    }
```

Changes at the xml file:

```
<visitor>
        <page>faq.xhtml</page>      
        <page>login.xhtml</page>
        <page>main.xhtml</page> 
        <page>registration.xhtml</page>
        <page>registrationbuyer.xhtml</page>    
        <page>registrationseller.xhtml</page>
    </visitor>
```

Changes made to the Access bean:

```
@XmlElement
    private User visitor;

public User getVisitor() {
        return visitor;
    }
```

Comment: I think one reason might be that i am not covering the possibility that the user might just be visiting the site and is not logged in at all as any of the users.If so how could i fix that?

Comment: any time you "only see white" in your browser, you should examine the response headers and content actually sent by your server (there are several browser extensions) to understand what is really going on. You can't examine the visual content that the browser renders alone to really understand what is going on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't see anything, then the Filter has blocked the request. I.e. it has neither continued the chain, nor forwarded or redirected the request. Your code flow is illogical. You should also do the redirect as well when the current user is `null` or when the current user does not have any of those roles. You should also call `chain.doFilter()` or `response.sendRedirect()` **effectively only once** throughout entire filter's code. Right now you're calling them multiple times for each page inside a loop. Those method calls do not magically abort the `for` loop.

I'd suggest to rewrite the main `if` block as follows

```
   boolean authorized = false;

   if (currentUser != null) {
        if (currentUser.getType().equals("BUYER")) {
            for (String s : access.getBuyer().getPages()) {
                if (pageRequested.contains(s)) {
                    authorized = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
        } else if (currentUser.getType().equals("SELLER")) {
            for (String s : access.getSeller().getPages()) {
                if (pageRequested.contains(s)) {
                    authorized = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
        } else if (currentUser.getType().equals("ADMINISTRATOR")) {
            for (String s : access.getAdministrator().getPages()) {
                if (pageRequested.contains(s)) {
                    authorized = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    if (authorized) {
        chain.doFilter(request, response);
    } else {
        resp.sendRedirect("main.xhtml");
    }
```

I'd personally also make the `CurrentUser#getType()` an `enum` so that you can use a `switch` instead of `if else if else if else ...` and refactor the three duplicated blocks into a single helper method.

---

**Update**: as per your redirect loop issue, if your filter is mapped on a generic URL pattern like `/*` (which **also** covers `main.xhtml`) instead of e.g. `/secured/*`, then you need to **not** redirect the request when the currently requested page is `main.xhtml`, but you need to continue the chain instead. You can do this by skipping the main `if` check whenever the currently requested page is `main.xhtml`. You don't care about the authorization for `main.xhtml` anyway.

Comment: I did as you said, my getUserType returns an enum and i handle it with a switch statement. The browsers says that there is a redirect loop. I pasted the last changes to my code in the update above

Comment: See answer update. Modify your `if` block. E.g. `if (notInMainXhtml && currentUser != null)`.

Comment: Im sorry but im not sure if i understood. I deleted the main surrounding if that says  if (currentUser != null) {, now i dont see white but i get a NPE at this line: switch (currentUser.getType()) { That is because the user is not logged in i think i needed that if

Comment: You need to replace `if (currentUser != null)` by `if (notInMainXhtml && currentUser != null)`. The `notInMainXhtml` is supposed to be the condition which evaluates `true` if the requested page is not `main.xhtml`. E.g. `if (!pageRequested.endsWith("/main.xhtml") && currentUser != null)`.

Comment: I did this 
if(!pageRequested.contains("main.xhtml") && currentUser != null) but i still get that redirect loop when i navigate to main.xml if i try to navigate to any other page i get redirected to main.xml so i see the redirect loop again. Also i whant to mention that the start page of my project is index.jsp i dont know if that affects something

Comment: Sorry, that check has to go in the `if (authorized)` block as well. E.g. `if (pageRequested.contains("main.xhtml") || authorized)`

Comment: Now it works, i can access main.xhtml but i cannot travel to any other page, everytime i try to go to another page(Example:faq.xhtml) i get redirected to main.xml. Something is wrong in the xml?

Comment: Then `authorized` has evaluated as `false`. Debug the code why it is not been set to `true`.

Comment: It is false because when i build i am not logged in so it goes to the else{ sendRedirect("main.xhtml") Does this mean i have to add another condition in the lower if? I think what i should do is also chain when not authorized. But how?

Comment: Then the filter is doing its job correctly. You need to login in order to access the page! :) If you don't want to login everytime when developing pages, you could add a global setting such as `-Ddevelopment=true` and add another conditional check `boolean development = "true".equals(System.getProperty("development"));` and include this check.

Comment: Those rules in the xml are only for logged users, but not logged users also should be able to navigate, to some pages like login.xml register.xml, faq.xhtml... Currently the filter is not allowing to my not logged users to move from main.xml. I think i did something is wrong, but what?

Comment: Then add extra rules for non-logged-in users to allow them access. Or do the other way round, use a blacklist instead of whitelist.

Comment: That is what i am thinking, but i will have another problem then. My object Role, is only saved in the session when the user logs in, how can i control when the user is not logged in? currentType() cannot return to me NOT_LOGGED, because it is not saved in the session. What can i do? I think adding just a tag <VISITOR> to my xml would not be enough

Comment: Just check if `currentUser` is null or not.

Comment: What should i do when currentUser is null? I did add an else statement to handle when null and did a few modifications at the xml and the Access class, now when i build and go to the app in the browser i get NPE again at this line:  for (String s : access.getVisitor().getPages()) { I think i am near the solution but i dont know what to do?

Comment: I fixed the problem sorry for the confusion. It was a bit stupid, for some reason i also had a local variable called access and that confused the the filter, because there was also a global variable with that name. Now it works fine. Not loged used can see the pages defined in the .xml :) Thank you